# Detaching objects that have collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework-4

I have the following code in my DAL:

```
public List<User> Getuser(int userId)
        {
            using (var context = this.GetDataContext())
            {
                var user = (from u in context.Users.Include("UserRoles")
                            where u.UserId == userId
                            select u).FirstOrDefault();

                context.Detach(user);

                return user;
            }
        }
```

When detach is called I lose my UserRole Collection that I am trying to send back to the client VIA WCF. If I don't detach the object from the context I get 'The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.'.  What is the best way of doing so I can preserve the collection without having to re-query it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off lazy loading for this operation. Your entities most probably contains other relations and WCF tries to serialize them as well.